# How to install AssaultCube in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, 20.04

I downloaded the [AssaultCube](https://assault.cubers.net/) .bzip installation file, but I am new to Ubuntu so I don't know how to install the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AssaultCube is a first-person shooter set in a realistic-looking environment. The arcade-style gameplay is fast-paced and favors team oriented, multiplayer fun. AssaultCube can be installed in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu from Ubuntu Software or from the terminal with the following command:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install assaultcube assaultcube-data
```

Comment: i downloaded the tar.bz2 file from the website and i don't know understand all they were saying like install libraries so ho do i do it

Comment: @chi67 All the libraries are in assaultcube-data. Just run `sudo apt update && sudo apt install assaultcube assaultcube-data` and you're done.

Comment: but the official packages do NOT include the AntiCheat part of the distributed binaries in the release download package. The installation of the required libraries is discussed here: [getting started](https://assault.cubers.net/docs/getstarted.html) and [Linux Support](https://wiki.cubers.net/action/view/Linux_Support) .. ubuntu 20.04 and AC1.2 have issues, the project is currently working on a 1.3 release.